# Do we as humans develop tolerance to deodorants or antiperspirants?

Tags: skin

Do we as humans develop tolerance to deodorants or antiperspirants? In particular when they contain isobutane, isopropyl, palmitate, isododecane, dimethicone, coconut oil, magnesium oxide, allantoin, dimethiconol, disteardimonium hectorite, propylene carbonate.

Comment: What do you mean by tolerance? This implies that by default we should have some reaction to these agents. What makes you think that?

Comment: I thought that these agents might modify the behaviour of sweat glands, which is itself some reaction.

Comment: deodorants don't modify sweat glands they just act to mask or absorb scents. some anti antiperspirants act to plug sweat glands.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John. Can you please restrict to the effects of the substances that I've listed? What about long term effects then? In other words, if I stop using deodorants/anti perspirants, does my body revert back to when I hadn't started using them yet? The answer to this is not obvious, in particular given your comment "some anti antiperspirants act to plug sweat glands."